# Is there anything similar to "TabOut" for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio Code, the extension [TabOut](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut) allows you to get out of brackets and quotes using the 'Tab' key.

Is there any extension similar to this in Visual Studio 2019?